# Inner join with sub query in hql

Tags: hibernate

```
SELECT id, comment, team_name 
    from XYZ
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id 
    from ABC 
    where team.id= "XYZ" 
    GROUP BY id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
) on XYZ.id=ABC.id where XYZ.id="ABC"
```

What will be the solution to this problem as i am not able to do inner join on subquery in HQL.

Comment: Your subquery makes no sense.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From sub-query i want to fetch all same team members in the DESC order according to their star rating and from outer query i want to do inner join so that all data from Star table is fetched in DESC order

Comment: In Star table multiple team and their members are their so in inner query i am just getting all same team members in DESC order by using GROUP BY to eliminate redundancy

Comment: Using `ORDER BY` in the subquery has no effect on the order of the outer result set.

Comment: But i can fetch first element which is **assignedTo** from first row and use **Where outer.assignedTo=inner.assignedTo** in the outer table and get that particular row only to maintain order.

Comment: Please add some sample data which makes if clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to use `GROUP BY` for all the columns

```
SELECT s.assignedTo.id, s.assignedBy.id, s.comment, s.assignedTo.team.team_name, COUNT(s.assignedTo.id) 
FROM Star s 
WHERE s.assignedTo.team.team_id=:teamName  
GROUP BY s.assignedTo.id,s.assignedBy.id, s.comment,s.assignedTo.team.team_name
ORDER BY s.assignedTo.id;
```